# Apache's .htaccess container to match domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have 2 domains pointing to the same folder,
I need to put up a .htaccess file to change cache behaviour on the first domain.

Please don't suggest to edit the server's vhost configuration, this question is specifically for .htaccess.

Something like:

```
<Match http://domain1.test.com>
    Header unset ETag
</Match>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ [L,E=TESTDOMAIN:1]

# Do not use etags for cache validation.
Header unset ETag env=TESTDOMAIN
# for older Apache versions
Header unset ETag env=REDIRECT_TESTDOMAIN
```